# Flutter iOS build failure error on Android Studio/iOS Simulator

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to run a flutter app on iOS Simulator using Android Studio.

Flutter iOS build failure error on Android Studio/iOS Simulator

error: Multiple commands produce

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.

**I'm using Android Studio and Mac M1**

Flutter 1.22.2
Dart 2.10.2

```
Launching lib/main_prod.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           11.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7FC279E9-A458-41A0-B69A-C1EC3242DF62, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:05F87F03-B88F-459C-AEFC-26C2385D233C, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6C13AA37-D545-438A-8BED-776EDDBC2A14, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8178B258-3A00-4BC3-9947-7FC3B0DE47FF, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6CA00F98-8C1D-4AA9-9419-20BF4632AEE5, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EA655090-1CEF-492F-AA36-039BF47607CB, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6B7AE738-4CA8-4DB9-928E-3C8DB6073DAB, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AFDEAE82-FEDF-46DC-B55C-499D08072FB7, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:142EF794-9784-4DAC-92AF-902DDAB2E903, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0A8C2062-001B-462B-8BD8-FEBDBD78B7C3, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BB60FC87-E13F-44D7-AB6A-41F4B8629F09, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FFE01BF7-1412-4CC0-B2F2-C5FB201A3AE6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AB4F5ED8-02A7-4683-97B3-D12813D1CBC1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:05820DE9-0EA4-4BB5-899E-3D5516132DC9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AA83853C-D24E-44C3-A0CF-F35AF6FC7D4D, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B142861E-398C-436F-8995-08DF8F20A8E0, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BAD30648-A9DC-41A9-93C0-83E53DE559FA, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FE295A43-6232-4A75-976B-77DEDFAAA058, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1CFEDA55-B155-438A-93B4-209B20E838BD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EDA344B8-49E7-461F-908E-1FF46C0BA005, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FFFE448C-7C27-4AAF-8955-F912DFB2B520, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:23054B1D-0FB6-5B89-978F-31A66D93E939 }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/flutter/build/ios/Debug-RunnerDronline-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car':
    1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has compile command with input '/Users/flutter/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'device_info' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'firebase_remote_config' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'file_picker' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'open_mail_app' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'pdf_viewer_plugin' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'flutter_webview_plugin' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'wakelock' from project 'Pods')
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/flutter/build/ios/Debug-RunnerDronline-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Assets.car' on task: PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Copy Pods Resources /Users/ravin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-glymqpmchynexghjyxgnxbyoxxgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-RunnerDronline-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-F5C4C49F23F2E6725031FFEA.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'video_player' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'flutter_secure_storage' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'flutter_app_badger' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'esys_flutter_share' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'package_info' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'permission_handler' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'store_redirect' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'flutter_local_notifications' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'contacts_service' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'local_auth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'devicelocale' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'firebase_dynamic_links' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
```

Comment: Open your code in Xcode > Preference > location > derived data then remove your project folder and dependency from derived data. Clean your project then run.

Comment: @ShriSamarth Tried that it shows as default.. still facing the same error